# a11y - Should a list of buttons be a tablist or keep as a list of buttons?

Tags: accessibility, wai-aria

I've got a list of buttons that filter a catalog in a SPA app. The structure looks like this:

```
<div>
  <button>filter 1</button>
  <button>filter 2</button>
  <button>filter 3</button>
</div>
<div>
   {results}
</div>
```

Clicking each of button causes new results to be fetched from a server and then updated in the area {results}.

We've got an accessibility expert that is insisting that we change the above structure to be a tablist, but I don't see how it would work, as from my understanding, a tablist needs tabs and a corresponding tabpanel. The buttons could be the tabs, but what of the tabpanel? I don't have the data pre-existing, it must be fetched when the buttons are clicked.

How would I update the above to make it comply with accessibility?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It kind of feels like a tablist because clicking on the buttons essentially changes your view but there is not an accessibility reason that you **have to** use the [tablist design pattern](https://www.w3.org/WAI/ARIA/apg/patterns/tabpanel/).

I agree that you'd sort of be "forcing" it into the pattern since you only have one panel that updates rather than three separate panels.

It's perfectly fine to have a group of 3 buttons all update the same container and **not** use a tablist.

Is it obvious to the non-sighted user that they have 3 buttons to choose from?  If not, it might be nice to have them contained in a list.  You can use a real `<ul>` and turn off the bullet point styling or use `role="list"` and `role="listitem"`.

```html
<div role="list">
  <span role="listitem">
    <button>filter 1</button>
  </span>
  <span role="listitem">
    <button>filter 2</button>
  </span>
  <span role="listitem">
    <button>filter 3</button>
  </span>
</div>
```

I used `<span>` containers for the buttons to keep the inline nature of your original example.

Next, is it obvious to the non-sighted user that the page has updated when the button was selected?  It might be as simple as saying "selecting a button will update the results" or it might be obvious from the button labels.  Depending on your situation, [`aria-live`](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria/#aria-live) *might* be needed.  But that's going beyond the extend of your original question.

Comment: That's a good idea, with the roles - is there anyway to make it also behave like a tablist? eg. using a screen reader - you should be able to navigate the options using the left/right arrow keys. And tabbing will only take you to the first item in the tablist, the next tab should take you off the entire tablist altogether - whereas currently tabbing will go through each button

Comment: No, that would violate expectations on navigation. Tab key is expected to move focus to the next button.

Comment: If you want to implement left/right arrow navigation between the buttons, then you're getting closer and closer to a tab navigation widget and should probably use that design pattern.  Occasionally I see menus of buttons that use left/right arrow navigation and that works fine.  You don't necessarily have to `TAB` to each button, although that's the common expected behavior.